# Thingsboard: Plot charts with past data

Tags: plot, charts, thingsboard

I was wondering if anybody can help me in plotting a chart in Thingsboard with the past data.

[image]

I was able to build a widget that will plot the latest received value array. Now I want to plot a custom chart with the row values that I click on from the timeseries table.

Thanks in advance.